# Implementing a chat and inbox message like SO using websockets

Tags: php, websocket, redis, phpwebsocket

On doing some research I found that SO uses websockets for chat and message inbox notifications (with some blend of redis).I want to implement similar system and I have just started websockets and stuck to select the best approach.

I have arrived at the below strategy for this. As soon as a user logs in, I will open a connection for him.

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        //add user to the database or data structure
    }
```

I am thinking of representing each user with his unique id(registration id) on backend, so that I can identify users uniquely.

> Q.1 How can I store this extra ID information with `ConnectionInterface` object so that when I am sending message, I have reference of connection for a particular user and I can route message to that selected user, say ID=20.

```
foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if($client->id == $receiver_id)
                $client->send($msg);
        }
```

For example, when user with IDs 43, 54 and 78 are chatting, and 43 sent to 54 & 78, I can send message to all in the chat room except the sender itself. This way private chat is also handled, as there will only be two users at that time.

> Q.2 Secondly, should I maintain a local data structure like heap at backend to store this information of chat room ids and corresponding users or use redis. Which one will be more reliable and give good performance ( I know nothing about redis, just learnt that SO uses, so need to clear before investing time on redis)
>
> Q.3 How will I identify between chat message and inbox notifications on client side, as from server I can simply send the message.

I have thought of this solution as sending identifier tags, like 0 - chat, 1-inbox alert 2-reputation change, etc. Is this approach correct?

> Q.4 The user may have two or more chat rooms open simultaneously. How will I differentiate at the beckend?

I thought of this as every chat room will have its unique identifier string, that will be sent along with message every time and using this string, I can identify the proper chat room at the backend, to which the message should be posted.Is this approach correct?

> Q.5 If answer to Q.2 is redis, can I use Redis with Mysql in parallel?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602100/real-time-pubsub-chat-with-history-via-websockets)