# Real-time pubsub chat with history via websockets

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket, redis, chat

I'm interested in creating what Disqus have done with their commenting system: http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/5/7/update-on-disqus-its-still-about-realtime-but-go-demolishes.html

The most impressive part of infrastructure is Nginx push stream module:

> Still runs on 5 machines Nginx machines.
>
> Uses NginxPushStream, which supprts EventSource, WebSocket, Long
>   Polling, and Forever Iframe.
>
> All users are connected to these machines.
>
> On a normal day each machine sees 3200 connections/s, 1 million
>   connections, 150K packets/s TX and 130K packets/s RX, 150 mbits/s TX
>   and 80 mbits/s RC, with <15ms delay end-to-end (which is faster than
>   Javascript can render a comment)
>
> Had many issues with resource exhaustion at first. The configuration
>   for Nginx and the OS are given that help alleviate the problems,
>   tuning them to handle a scenario with many connections moving little
>   data.

Obviously this Nginx module doesn't support data storage. Only in-memory mechanism supported by **push_stream_store_messages** directive, but [as author said](https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module/issues/193):

> The main target to stored messages is to deliver the message to a
>   subscriber that was offline when the message was published.

It is clear that Disqus don't publish messages to Nginx directly but rather though the Go backend that manages to store messages in Redis followed by publishing via internal POST to Nginx which keeps subscribers.

Does anyone have an experience with fetching messages history through Redis on a page load before even we use push stream module for newer messages? Do you have to push old messages history in one go or render as plain HTML followed by pubsub for new messages that appear after page is loaded?

The logic needs to be decoupled as much as possible. I don't intend to introduce blocking mechanism between user and Nginx for real time message communication. Would that be a good solution below?

1. Client pushes the message from the web page (via websockets)
2. Ajax request goes straight to push stream location and on Ajax complete callback it requests backend to store message in Redis (in the other direction it gets locked with backend)
3. Once user refreshes the page backend fetches Redis list and display the history
4. User can see the history and can post new messages

It requires only 2 backend requests to be developed: accept message and store in Redis, fetch the data and display on page load. Preferably light non-blocking backend required, like [Lua module](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module) or even HTTP interface to Redis called  [Webdis](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis).

I'd like to know smart people opinion on that mechanism from architecture point of view, no code example expected.

Comment: I think that your solution might be a good one, but I have the following question: when the client pushes the message from the web page, you instantly update it's UI with the message he just wrote? If so, what if the things go wrong and the Ajax request fails? You have to revert somehow the UI, in order make it consistent, because it would be a bad UX if the message shows that it has been posted but when I refresh the page, it disappears because it hasn't been stored in Redis.

Comment: there is no Ajax. User pushes messages to nginx-push-stream-module via websockets and Nginx tries hard until it gets delivered to subscribers. Nginx automatically store message via post_action. If original request fails we need to display "not delivered" or some kind of acknowledgement.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in [nchan](https://nchan.slact.net/) — it's from the author of Nginx HTTP Push Module from which pushstream was forked. It can buffer messages in Redis (search for Redis on the homepage --> _"It can buffer messages in memory, on-disk, or via Redis"_). I'm not sure but perhaps nchan will give you the-N-most-recent-chat-messages automatically.