# NGINX + Lua multipart/form-data how to read only text POST params and discard file uploads?

Tags: nginx, lua, http-post, multipartform-data

I have a small `ngx_lua` script which is collecting some usage statistics to Redis (lua-resty-redis) via `post_action` and I want to collect only text parameters and discard file uploads.

My config:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
daemon  off;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
      proxy_read_timeout  30s;
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:8081;
      proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header  Connection  "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwaded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

      post_action @post_action;
    }

    location /test {
      content_by_lua_file capture.lua;
    }

    location @post_action {
      internal;
      content_by_lua_file capture.lua;
    }
  }
}
```

Lua script (simplified):

```
local json = require "cjson"
local redis = require "resty.redis"
local red = redis:new()

red:set_timeout(1000)

local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)

if not ok then
    ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
    return
end

local data = {}

ngx.req.read_body()

local data = json.encode(ngx.req.get_post_args())

local ok, err = red:rpush("post_data", data)

if not ok then
    ngx.say("failed to push request data: ", err)
    return
end
```

When I receive a request with both file and text, the script crashes with this error:

`requesty body in temp file not supported`

Comment: Fixed by ignoring multipart requests.

Comment: Nginx post_action with conjunction of redis is very efficient! Off-topic but how did you compile Nginx with LuaJit, lua redis and cjson module? It comes with OpenResty but I prefer use standard Nginx build with minimal set of required modules instead.

Comment: Andrey, take a look [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602100/real-time-pubsub-chat-with-history-via-websockets), you may know an answer so I can give you +100 bounty in case of great answer

Comment: OK, as your problem fixed and you have expertise with Lua/Redis would you try to answer [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602100/real-time-pubsub-chat-with-history-via-websockets) question?